# Bootstrap navbar toggle button not showing contents

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Currently when the screen is minimized, the toggle button appears, but I would like to be able to click it and see the contents of the navbar when the screen is regular size.  Currently clicking it doesn't do anything.  Is there a way to resolve this without JS?

This is my HTML page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Great Songs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'great_songs:great_songs' %}">Great Songs</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:artists' %}">Artists <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:genres' %}">Genres</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:producers' %}">Producers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:labels' %}">Labels</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  <div class="container">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without JS it means without any code js? or you don't need to call bootstrap.js library?

Comment: bootstrap also required jquery

Comment: without any code js.  I'm following this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ which doesn't mention anything about js or bootstrap.js library

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write your own code to make it works, but you need to also include  bootstraps js library and its dependencies (jQuery + popper.js), here you will find information how should you do it https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/

in case you have some issues with that let me know I will show you how to implement it to your code

@edit:
 FYI bootstrap.css, provide for you only bunch of css classes which you can use for quick styling but it doesn't provides any interactivity unless those supported by css such as element hover or focus

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Great Songs</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'great_songs:great_songs' %}">Great Songs</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:artists' %}">Artists
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:genres' %}">Genres</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:producers' %}">Producers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:labels' %}">Labels</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, for someone who is pretty new to coding, I'm not sure how to implement this stuff, or why I have to or what it does, even.  If you wouldn't mind helping me implement it that would be very helpful!

Comment: I inserted the following two lines of code at the end, but they don't seem to have an effect:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Nevermind!  Got it working using a different set of links for jquery.  I still don't fully understand this though so if there's any literature or documentation on what exactly this stuff is and how to use it, that would definitely be useful.

Comment: @leaozinho sorry bro I was away for weekend, i edited my answer, so you can see the working code, you just added jquery library, but you also need to add bootstrap and popper as it dependencies